# "Дошёл до кухни" или "дошёл к кухне"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Вот, например: "подойти к кухне". Правильно же? А "дошёл до" или "дошёл к"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дойти до кухни, подойти к кухне.

Это тема **соответствия глагольной приставки и предлога** при обозначении движения.

**До-**. Соотносится с предлогом «до» и обозначает движение до какого-н. предмета: добежать до дверей, донести чемодан до вокзала, или доведение действия до конца, до какого-н. момента: дописать письмо, дочитать книгу до середины.

**Под-** (подо-, подъ-). Обозначает движение, действие, направленное к предмету или под предмет: подбежать к окну, подойти к товарищу, подложить подушку под голову (в большинстве употреблений
противоп. от-; ср. при-).

Материал взят из источника [Значения глагольных приставок | polyidioms.narod.ru](http://polyidioms.narod.ru/index/glagolnye_pristavki/0-205)